# parallel.for - что с ним не так?

Tags: c#, winforms, циклы, textbox

У меня есть задача - создать табличку из текстбоксов, ширина `TableWidth`, высота `TableHeigth`. Для больших значений (50*50) табличка создается довольно долго, поэтому решил сделать параллельную отрисовку по строчкам. Но данный код полностью весит программу. Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть не так? Есть предположения что где-то выполняется потоконебезопасная операция, но где именно...

```
Parallel.For(1, table.TableWidth + 1, x =>
{
    var i = x;
    for (int y = 1; y <= table.TableHeight; y++)
    {
        var j = y;
        TextBox textbox;
        if (!textBoxes.ContainsKey(new Point(i, j)))
        {
            textbox = new TextBox();
            textBoxes.Add(new Point(i, j), textbox);
            textbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            Controls.Add(textbox);
        }

        textbox = textBoxes[new Point(i, j)];
        textbox.Location = new Point(ColumnsCoords[i], RowsCoords[j]);
        textbox.Width = table.ColumnsWidth[i];
        textbox.Height = table.RowsHeight[j];
        textbox.Text = table[i, j].Data;

        textbox.GotFocus += (s, a) =>
        {
            focusedCellCoords.Text = new Point(i, j).ToString();
            currentTextBox = textbox;
            focusedCell.Text = textbox.Text;
        };
        textbox.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
        {
            PushData(new Point(i, j), textbox.Text);
            currentTextBox = textbox;
            focusedCell.Text = textbox.Text;
        };
    }

});
```

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память весь UI должен быть в одном потоке и разнести его по разным потокам требует не только бубен, но и опытного шамана. Ну и традиционный вопрос - WPF или WinForms?

Comment: В данном случае использую WinForms

Comment: А что означает «долго»? И я не вижу в вашем коде серьёзных вычислений, так что сильно сомневаюсь, что разбивка на потоки поможет. И да, все контролы должны создаваться в UI-потоке, так что вынести в фоновый поток можно разве что длинные вычисления.

Comment: Слишком много вопросов по вашему коду. Что такое `table`? Коллекция `textBoxes` потокобезопасная? Планируется ли в дальнейшем удаление этих текстбоксов? События в виде лямбд не дадут отписаться от них - возможна утечка памяти.

Comment: И вообще, не проще ли взять компонент типа `DataGridView`? Или, например, `TableLayoutPanel` для размещения текстбоксов?

Comment: Parallel внутри себя зря ресурсов не тратит и один из используемых внутри его потоков тот, с которым мы начали этот Parallel, то есть из допустим 4х потоков (сколько ядер) один из них всегда будет UI поток, а для создания таблицы ВСЕМ нужен UI поток, потому все и висит

Comment: @vitidev - Теоретически, можно передать в `Parallel.For` кастомный `TaskScheduler`, который не будет использовать UI thread.

Comment: Добавление контролов в родительскую коллекцию - долгая операция. Чтобы ускорить ваш код, используйте вызов метода [SuspendLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Даже если бы приведенный вами код не вешал программу - он бы не смог работать. Дело в том, что любой контрол слушает события в том потоке, в котором был создан. Но цикл обработки сообщений крутится только в главном потоке приложения, потоки пула не могут получить оконных сообщений. Поэтому, ваши текстбоксы не будут реагировать на события (в них даже нельзя ввести текст, ввод текста тоже требует активного цикла обработки сообщений).

Единственное возможное решение - выкинуть `Parallel.For` и заменить его на обычный цикл `for`.

---

Что же до "подвешивания" программы - рискну предположить, что происходит взаимоблокировка в строчке `Controls.Add(textbox);` - наверняка этому методу надо отправить оконное сообщение в главный поток UI, а он как раз занят циклом `for`. Но это гадание, если нужна точность - запустите отладчик и проверьте где оно висит точно.

Еще одна ваша возможная ошибка - судя по коду, textBoxes - это обычный словарь (`Dictionary<Point,TextBox>`). Но со словарем нельзя работать из нескольких потоком одновременно! Если бы код вообще имел смысл, вам следовало бы использовать `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` для той же цели.

Answer (score -1):

Есть смысл реализовать в виде обычного цикла, как и написали выше, но обернуть его в async/await. Тогда долгий цикл не будет вешать GUI.

Можно посмотреть тут https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/

Comment: Не поможет. В цикле создаются контролы (его нельзя вытащить в другой поток) и нет долгих операций.